# doPost is not running in appscript side, while setting it as webhook url in dialog flow

Tags: google-apps-script, dialogflow-es, webhooks

I am trying to use app-script published URL(with Anyone, even anonymous settings) as a webhook URL in dialog flow agent.
Here is the code i am using in appscript:

```
function doPost(e)
{
 console.log(e.postData.contents)
}
```

When i am trying to interact with web demo URL, i am not getting any execution log which states that **doPost** function has executed!

Settings in dialog flow fulfillment side :- [image]

What i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Although, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot know the specification of webhook you want to use, in your situation, for example, when `return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok")` is put to the last line of `doPost` and setting it again, what result will you obtain? And, in your situation, when `doPost` is accessed, you can confirm whether the script of Web Apps is run. But, your `console.log(d.postData.contents)` cannot see the log, because the access token is not used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: By the way, when you modified the script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Also, please be careful about this.

Comment: Did you deploy the web app? Also your app needs to return either `HtmlOutput` or `TextOutput`. And your `d.postData.contents` should be `e.postData.contents` as your event argument is `e`.

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk Yes, I'd deployed the app with **Anyone, even anonymous setting** and it's returning **return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok")** as suggested by Tanaike. I've corrected the typing mistake here, but it was correct in app!

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for response. I've added the return in **doPost** as you suggested and redeployed the app with new version, still i am not getting execution log of **doPost** when i am checking it in script execution page. Atleast it should run the function, currently i think it is not even running the doPost when i am interacting with web demo page of dialogflow agent

Comment: where are you checking if your script is running ? Where are you checking the log ? check on [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cWf2.png) if the number executions is increasing. Also, create a doGet function and call the url from the browser to see if its increasing the calls and returning anything please.

Comment: @ewertonvsilva I am checking the Execution log in 4th menu option in the image you attached!, I have tried the same webapp url as a webhook with Telegram Bot API and it is working absolutely fine , every time i interact with Telegram bot doPost function execute and one log entry immediately appears in execution log of appscript! But when i am doing the same thing with DialogFlow Agent nothing is happening

Comment: Try the doGet() to see if that will work

Comment: It looks like the POST request might not be getting sent.

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk Yes, do you know how to resolve it, i checked everything I know, including options given my other members here on comment, but nothing worked

Comment: Sorry, no ;( It sounds like a DialogFlow issue and I'm not an expert in that area. You need to find someone who is. Maybe repost this question as a DialogFlow one insted of a GAS one. However,  prior to posting just make sure that you webhook does work with curl or Postman, this way you can confirm that DF is indeed the root of your problem.

Comment: How are you triggering the webhook in DialogFlow ? Is the Fulfillment being called, can you confirm it ?